# What is this section called in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I'm wondering what this section of the file explorer outlined in red is called? And how can you add a drive to it like there is for the `E:` drive?[image]

Comment: I've always called it the Explorer pane, or the Treeview. Back in the old days (win9x), the difference between "Open" and "Explore" was the presence of that pane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explorer's Folder Options menu calls it the "Navigation pane". And it should know. :)

This screen cap is from Windows 10, but earlier versions are similar.

View tab in ribbon | Options | View tab

[image]